# gganatogram & R: Problems in change organs names

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to translate to spanish the organs names in gganatogram package, a R package to plot anatograms and tissues based on ggplot2.

This run ok:

```
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(gridExtra)
  library(gganatogram)
```

I did check names and objects

```
  str(hgMale_key)

 'data.frame':  68 obs. of  4 variables:
  $ organ : chr  "thyroid_gland" "bone_marrow" "frontal_cortex" 
 "prefrontal_cortex" ...
  $ type  : chr  "other" "other" "nervous_system" "nervous_system" ...
  $ colour: chr  "#41ab5d" "#41ab5d" "purple" "purple" ...
  $ value : num  4.67 3.31 15.51 1.81 12.88 ...



  hgMale_key%>%
   filter(organ %in% c("liver", "heart", "prostate", "stomach", 
   "brain"))%>%
   gganatogram(fillOutline="lightgray", organism="human", sex="male", 
   fill="value") + theme_void()
```

[image: body]

```
  ##################################
 
  I tried to translate
  run ok:

  hgMale_key$organ= gsub("liver", "higado",hgMale_key$organ)

  This not run, the same last code to plot:

  hgMale_key%>%
   filter(organ %in% c("higado", "heart", "prostate", "stomach", 
   "brain"))%>%
   gganatogram(fillOutline="lightgray", organism="human", sex="male", 
   fill="value") + theme_void()
```

Error in stats::complete.cases(dat) :
no input has determined the number of cases

Comment: You could always fork the repository in Github and create a translation in your fork. You have to change the supporting files. For example, the function uses `mus_musculus.male_coords.tsv`. It is the file with the male anatomy coordinates for the organs. The organ names in this file need to match the organ names in your dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to set up a look-up table to translate from the Spanish names to the English names of the organs (you'll need to check these, as I just ran the names through Google Translate):

```r
es_key <- gganatogram::hgMale_key 

es_key$organos <- c("glándula tiroides", 
  "médula ósea", "corteza frontal", "la corteza prefrontal", 
  "glándula pituitaria", "aorta", "unión_gastroesofágica", 
  "ventriculo izquierdo", 
  "intestino ciego", "ileon", "recto", "nariz", "seno", "lengua",
  "Auricula izquierda", "válvula pulmonar", "la válvula mitral", 
  "pene", "faringe_nasal", "médula espinal", "garganta", "válvula tricúspide", 
  "diafragma", "higado", "estómago", "bazo", "duodeno", "vesicula biliar", 
  "páncreas", "colon", "intestino delgado", "apéndice", "músculo liso", 
  "vejiga_urinaria", "hueso", "cartilago", "esófago",
  "glándula salival", "glándula parótida", "glándula submandibular", 
  "piel", "pleura", "cerebro", "corazón", "glándula suprarrenal", 
  "ganglio linfático", "tejido adiposo", "músculo esquelético", 
  "leucocito", "lóbulo temporal", "apéndice_auricular", "arteria coronaria", 
  "hipocampo", "vas_deferens", "vesicula seminal", "epididimo", 
  "amigdala", "pulmón", "amigdala", "tráquea", "bronquio", "nervio", 
  "cerebelo", "hemisferio_cerebeloso", "riñón", "corteza renal", 
  "testiculo", "próstata")
```

This allows you to do:

```
es_key %>%
   filter(organos %in% c("higado", "estómago", "cerebro", "próstata")) %>%
   gganatogram(fillOutline = "lightgray", organism = "human", sex = "male", 
               fill = "value") + 
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Allan  for you reply, help me a lot. You could comment why my focus using gsub is wrong?.